# Browsing Security Token Service URL showing error

Tags: sharepoint-server, sts

I have SharePoint 2010 installed on my Box and when browsing locally my STS service URL I am getting the following error on this link:

```
http://<site name>/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc
```

> An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a policy export extension.
>   Extension: System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement
>   Error: Security policy export failed. The binding contains a TransportSecurityBindingElement but no transport binding element that implements ITransportTokenAssertionProvider. Policy export for such a binding is not supported. Make sure the transport binding element in the binding implements the ITransportTokenAssertionProvider interface. ----> System.InvalidOperationException: Security policy export failed. The binding contains a TransportSecurityBindingElement but no transport binding element that implements ITransportTokenAssertionProvider. Policy export for such a binding is not supported. Make sure the transport binding element in the binding implements the ITransportTokenAssertionProvider interface.
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement.System.ServiceModel.Description.IPolicyExportExtension.ExportPolicy(MetadataExporter exporter, PolicyConversionContext policyContext)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExporter.ExportPolicy(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
>      --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---

few people suggested to fix this Error by applying the following lines on Web.Config of STS Service:

```
Change all httpTransport binding to httpsTransport binding.
Add allowInsecureTransport=”true” and enableUnsecuredResponse=”true” 
to the binding security.
```

But Actually this modifications on Web.Config Stops UPSA and Managed Meta Data Service and make them inaccessible.

I have read few articles online and my research leads me to WCF Hotfix that supposed to be running during SharePoint Installation process after installing Prerequisites, this makes REST-based Web services work properly in SharePoint Foundation, I tried to download and run this package on my box but it says that its not applicable on this computer. :
[Link to ADO.NET Data Services Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8165)

My Box Sepx are:

1. SharePoint 2010 SP2 + latest Patches Sep 2015.
2. .Net Framework 4.5.1 installed
3. SQL 2008 R2
4. Windows server 2008 R2 Ent.

appreciate your ideas to fix this issue, and getting back my STS URL browsing properly.